# In control4 how can I use of Pool Proxy

Tags: proxy, pool, home-automation

Could anyone please guide in regards with the pool proxy development process. As the provided documentation (Proxy and Protocol guide) explains only about proxy classes but needing few more help and the directions to develop the pool proxy. Is there any roadmap as how to develop our own proxies for the driver or simply the scenario.

Please guide with above query, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be a Control4 Developer to gain access to their SDK which includes a Pool Template.